# Spring MVC or some other frameworks to support .jsp extension in URL

Tags: java, url, spring-mvc, web, mapping

I am supposed to redesign a web application that was originally created in JSP. However, I have two important requirements that this application should meet.

1. This new web application shall be able to keep its existing direct URL structure, that looks like this: http://existingurl.org/appname/file.jsp?id=0000000000001&optionalParams=something
2. It shall Support Javascript and AJAX (But I think that this one is not really a problem nowadays)

My first choice was spring MVC due to its popularity, but as far as I know the URL structure in Spring MVC would not support the  *file**.jsp*** part of the URL. In Spring the URL would look like this:
http://existingurl.org/appname/file/id/0000000000001?optionalParams=something  because it tends to hide the extension.

Is there any way to support this `direct URL` from my first requirement with Spring MVC? Or would you recommend me any other framework?

Comment: You need to add the resourceHandler for your application in the applicationContext.xml file to allow .jsp style URL requests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spring mvc will absolutely let you keep your mapping.  You can map it how you like!