# How to provide support for URLs with .jsp extension in spring

Tags: java, url, spring-mvc, web, mapping

[I have been told in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16081066/spring-mvc-or-some-other-frameworks-to-support-jsp-extension-in-url) that it is possible to have .jsp extension in URL structure using Spring. I have been trying to achieve it with the following code:

HelloController.java

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/welcome")
public class HelloController {
    @RequestMapping(value="/item.jsp", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String helloDotJSP(ModelMap model) {

        System.out.println("/item.jsp RequestMapping");
        model.addAttribute("message", "Spring 3 MVC Hello World");
        return "item";
    }
}
```

And when I try to access the page **localhost:8080/app/welcome/item.jsp** I get the error that *The requested resource is not available.* But when I try to just modify the extension from **/item.jsp**  to for example **/item.other** it starts working. How can I add support for **.jsp** extension?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: I'm wondering why you would want that... Anyway, do you want all your mappings to use this extension, or is it the application in general?

Comment: One of my requirement is to provide backward compatibility with existing URL infrastructure. I don't know if I will need all my mappings to use this extension but there will be more than one for sure.

Comment: I see. I'm guessing the default JSP servlet is interfering with your url pattern. Have you considered using URL-rewriting for the existing URLs instead? Then you could expose the "old" URL while transparently using regular Spring URL mappings behind it.

Comment: I did. I've found [UrlRewriteFilter](http://tuckey.org/urlrewrite/) but it seemed to me like a big workaround for small problem that might have been solved by a proper mapping in Spring. I'm not really experienced in Spring that's why I've created this question.

Comment: I think you have to re-map the default JSP servlet somehow. See here for a suggestion: http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?13263-Using-.jsp-extension

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the "requested resource is not available" because I your servlet mapping in the `web.xml` is not mapping `item.jsp` to the Spring `DispatcherServlet`.

Regardless, if your requirement is just to support old URLs, there are more effective ways of doing it.

Most lo-fi is to create jsps that with the same name and structure as the old urls, and in each of these jsps add scriptlets like

```
<%
response.setStatus(301);
response.setHeader( "Location", "/new-url.htm" );
response.setHeader( "Connection", "close" );
%>
```

I don't usually recommend scriptlets but in cases like these, its the simplest solution.

You can also add 301 redirect rules if you have a fronting webserver like apache.

Hope this helps.